# Three finger drag with trackpad?

Tags: trackpad

OS X has a feature where you can use three fingers to do the equivalent of click-and-drag, sparing you the annoying tap-then-tap-again-and-move-quickly dance normally required.

Is there a way to enable this on Ubuntu for, say, moving tabs around in Chrome?

Note: I'm aware that Unity has re-purposed three finger gestures. I'm not using Unity, and very much want generic click-and-drag via three finger touch.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu does different: Double tap, but dont release. Is the new three finger drag. Also, it works the same on Windows (not that it matters), and works quite ok for me, for now.

Just had to find out, that was the hardest part.

Comment: I'm sure there must be a way to configure it though, surely? That's probably the default in case someone is using hardware that can't understand 3 fingers? Fingers crossed! (3 of them)

Comment: it's still bugging me that a project like ubuntu (and gnome..) doesnt have a proper trackpad configuration tool. man, it's 2020.

Comment: and yeah, fingers crossed...I'm sure it IS doable, but only by hacking synaptic and/or libinput on our own... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have unity you should be able to just install touchegg from the Ubuntu Software Center and then for a nice gui you can download and install the touchegg gui from here: https://github.com/Raffarti/Touchegg-gce

Touchegg is awesome by the way! I programmed 3,4 and 5 finger gestures to do anything i wanted. You can program clicks as well as different swipes as well. it's pretty awesome.

Comment: Can you explain how to configure touchegg for three-finger drag?

Comment: really missing the three finger drag on ubuntu! is there an up to date solution for 2020 known of? touchegg is far outdated...

Comment: yeah, touchegg doesn't seem to support 3FD :( And I'm so used to it after years of using Mac

Answer (score 1):

You can build https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/building.html Ubuntu and has some cool features. It also has 3 finger gesture. You can configure it to do drag. Here https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/gestures.html. I am using it for Gnome Xorg in Ubuntu 20.04.[image]. I am also  trying to have the same 3 finger drag using Trackpad 2. By the way, libinput is smoother like in Macs than Touchegg.  I'll share my knowledge here while I go.

Comment: nice. this looks like the new way to do it! pls, keep us posted.